# how to using variable (dynamic data) with single quotes in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, variables, dynamic-data

based in my knowledge we cannot use a single quote with a variable (dynamic data) but in some cases the single quote is required ,so my question is there any way to make second code works?

the code without variable is working fine:-

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'Name -like "david*"'
```

the code with variable not returning any data:-

```
$fname = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the employee first name'
Get-ADUser -Filter 'Name -like "$fname*"'
```

Comment: Switch quotes. A variable only gets expanded in a double quoted string but your filter is a single quoted string. Try `Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like '$fname*'"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format the filter query using [`–f` operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html).

```
PS> $CustomFilter = 'Name -like "{0}*"' -f $fname
PS> $CustomFilter
Name -like "david*"
PS> Get-ADUser -Filter $CustomFilter
```